# How to use a view generated from another class?

Tags: android, view

The expanded_status_bar layout in AOSP 4.0.4 has a TextView that looks like this in the XML

```
<com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.DateView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

It is generated by "frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/DateView.java"

It is inflated by "frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/PhoneStatusBar.java" like so:

```
ExpandedView expanded = (ExpandedView) View.inflate(context, R.layout.status_bar_expanded, null);
// stuff here
mDateView = (DateView) expanded.findViewById(R.id.date);
```

I want to set its visibility via another class and I've tried a few things that I have read on here, all with no luck. The last thing I tried was, in my class (which is also part of systemui), to add the following:

```
TextView mDateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
mDateView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

However, it turns out mDateView is null in my class. Is there something I am missing? I've been looking all over for hours and trying things here and there but nothing works. I have intermediate-level Java skills and I am still trying to wrap my arms around the OOP thing having coming from 20 years of procedural languages. Thanks in advance.

I changed mDateView's definition to look like this:

```
private DateView mDateView;
DateView mDateView = (DateView) findViewById(R.id.date);
```

But I am still getting mDateView as being null :(

Comment: is the DateView class extends ExpandedView?

Comment: Hello i misunderstood your question, the solution is you add method in a class where you are inflating your view.

Comment: a method to set view invisible.

Comment: Dheeresh: in DateView.java I have "public final class DateView extends TextView {" and in PhoneStatusBar.java I have " ExpandedView expanded = (ExpandedView) View.inflate(context, R.layout.status_bar_expanded, null"

Comment: I tried that iNan but I still got mDateView is null. Let me find a link to the source. Maybe I put it in the wrong location.

Comment: Hello if you are using a method then you do not need to worry about reference to view.

Comment: iNan: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/PhoneStatusBar.java

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13008/discussion-between-gdanko-and-inan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially i misunderstood your question, you can add methods in one class and access it via another.

```
public static void hideDateView() {
        mDateView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

You can add the following method in **PhoneStatusBar**.java and Call it later.

Comment: @gdanko I have one doubt is DateView  extends ExpandedView class?

Comment: I dont think so, I was bit lazy to type `findViewById` i just copied from above :D

Comment: No. mDateView is still null :(

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems that I can see:

1) You will need to pass the `Context` that owns your `View` into the class that you want to use the view in.

Assuming that the `Context` is an `Activity`, you'd then use `activity.findViewById(R.id.date)`.

2) If you're going to use `findViewById(R.id.date)` you need to make sure that you have added the view to your view hierarchy somehow (inflating it doesn't do this unless you specifically tell it to).  The `inflate()` function provides a way to do this by passing in a parent view instead of `null` followed by an additional boolean argument that specifies whether or not the inflated view should be added to the parent.

Alternately, you could say `parentView.addView(expanded)` after your existing inflate call.

Comment: I tried creating a public method in PhoneStatusBar.java since that is the class that inflates the view. It was something like: public void hideDateView(Context c) { mDateView.setVisbility(View.GONE); } but I would get an NPE stating that mDateView is null. I may have put the method in the wrong location.